# Can the movie15 package work with Silverlight application?

Tags: movie15

Can the `movie15` package work with [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) application?

Silverlight is a browser plugin or application similar to Adobe Flash.

Comment: @Herbert: There is a good example of Silverlight here http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/. But please make sure you have Silverlight player (like Flash player) installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Movie15 uses the Adobe object embedding representation for PDFs, called Rich Media Annotations, which does not handle Silverlight.  That might change.

#### Resources

1. [PDF Reference and Adobe Extensions to the PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) — Extension level 3 contains the Rich Media Annotations;
2. [Rich media annotations and AcroFLeX](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95story.pdf), D.P. Story, TUG Boat 2009;
3. [Inserting rich media into PDF documents](http://www.adobe.com/education/resources/hed/instructional/connect/collaborative_teaching/pdfs/insert_rich_media_PDF.pdf) - Brief introduction by Adobe.